# Row Security level PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am finishing a report and I want to include on it dinamic RLS.

I have a table named PS_ACCESO_CENTRO which have logins and Center Codes, also as you can see I have a measure that indicate me the logging. This table could have duplicate values as one center is not restricted to only one center code.

Would it be possible to filter my Centros by the PS_ACCESO_CENTRO depending on the users that is logged?

if you think in any strategy it would be great as I am very new on this.

Thank you very much in advance,
Antonio

[table conexion model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Up0T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

First of all you have to create roles at `Modeling` tab.

[image]

Click `Manage roles` and create them.

[image]

Now in your DAX query you should compare `Login` with the current user. To access the latter you can use `USERNAME()` or `USERPRINCIPALNAME()` functions (see [here](https://www.spguides.com/difference-between-username-and-userprincipalname-in-power-bi-dax/) the differences, honestly, from my experience I don't get why they both exist, I only use `USERPRINCIPALNAME()` because it's consistent).

Also, if you deploy on `Power BI Report Server`, you'll need to assign users and groups to your created roles, otherwise it won't show anything.

Comment: That would be possible in the case my Centros table would appear the loging but it is not possible as there are many logins that can view multiple centres.

Comment: @Antoniooms I'm not sure what you mean. If you filter your `PS_ACCESO_CENTRO` table to only one, current user, and they are connected to multiple centres then they'll see them. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: Hi Ginkul, my PS_ACCESO_CENTRO is filtered by only one active user. and it shows only the centres that my user can view. Now what I have to achive is that my centros table get limitated to the same centres as PS_ACCESO_CENTROS filtered with the active user.

Comment: Can you look at the settings of the relation between those? There should be a checkbox `Apply security filter in both directions`, is it checked?